# How is this attribute value bound without interpolation markup?

Tags: angularjs

- MyController has clickedvalue as false in its scope.
- the click changes it to true
- the dir directive watches for change on the clicked attribute.
- How is the $watch seeing change - or how is the clickvalue changing without being interpolation markup {{clickvalue}}
- right now `click="clickvalue"` triggers the $watch which would mean it is 'bound' to the MyContoller's clickvalue

  ```
   <div ng-controller='MyController'>
    <button ng-click='click()'>Call function inside directive</button>
  <dir clicked="clickedvalue"></dir>  
  </div>
  ```

app.js

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.clickedvalue = false;
  $scope.click = function() {
  $scope.clickedvalue = !$scope.clickedvalue;
  };
 }
]);

appDirectives = angular.module('app.directives', []);

appDirectives.directive('dir', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope:    {
    clicked:   '='
    },
      link:function(scope, element, attrs ) {
        scope.$watch('clicked', function() {
        console.log('innerFunc called');
        })
      }
    };

   }]);
```

Comment: {{clickvalue}} this means interpalution directive used for one way binding..& `'='` inside scope option of directive used for two way binding..as parent value updated the value inside directive also gets updated.

Comment: ahh! thx - i guess information overload - missed that specific point to the '='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you well, the '=' does not require you to use {{interpolation}}, '@' would.

Moreover, take note that you set up the $watch on attribute, not on the controller's clickedvalue.

Answer (score 1):

In angular js `{{}}` means one way binding & when you are using directive and declaring isolated scope with using `=` that means two way binding of the scope variables. If one of variable changes then the relative scope updates.

```
scope: {
   clicked: '='
},
```

In your case `clicked` has been mapped with `clickedvalue`.As value of `clicked` gets update, it will also update the value of `clickedvalue` which is isolated scope directive

Comment: @jamie may be i was first commentor. :p